# Running 2 iOS simulators-- second one doesn't show any apps

Tags: ios, swift, terminal, ios-simulator

So I am running two iOS simulators but the second simulator doesn't show any of my apps. This is a screenshot of what happens:

[image]

The simulator on the left has my apps but the simulator on the right has no apps. Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Run your application as iPhone 6S simulator once. Then it will add it.

Comment: because you need to install your Xcode app differently for each simulator you initialise

Comment: You have to actually install the apps on the other simulator.

Comment: Thanks! It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your app to be shown in Different simulators then you have to select a particular simulator in which you want to run your app.

Note:- If you are running your app on iPhone 7 simulator then it will not be shown in iPhone 6S simulator. So, You have run your app on iPhone 6S simulator.